# Can we have multiple subscribers to same queue in websphere MQ?

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I am trying to have multiple threads (Task) from a windows service to connect to same queue as subscribers so that I can process my messages faster. When I connect to my queues, I am receiving messages on my first subscribed thread and the rest are idle. Following is the code I am using to subscribe and receive messages:

```
private MQQueueManager _queueManager;
private MQQueue _queue;
private MQTopic _topic;
public bool isSubscribed = false;

public void Subscribe()
{
    var queueManagerName = "myQueueManager";
    var properties = new Hashtable();
    //Set all the properties here
    _queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, properties);

    //Conect to Queue
    _queue = _queueManager.AccessQueue("devQueue", MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF);

    isSubscribed = true;
    while (isSubscribed)
    {
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            isSubscribed = false;
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
        try
        {
            Receive(onMessageReceived);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex);
        }
    }   
}


public override void Receive<T>(Action<T> onMessageReceived)
{
    try
    {
        var dataReceived = new MQMessage();
        _queue.Get(dataReceived);

        T message;
        message = (T)(object)dataReceived;

        onMessageReceived(message);     
        _queueManager.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

I also tried using `MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED` for accessing queue which did not work either. Am I missing something?

Comment: What version of MQ are you running (dspmqver output) please?

Comment: @JasonE Version 8.0

Answer (score 1):

The code you've quoted attempts to open and receive messages from a queue named "devQueue". If that code runs under multiple threads then the messages sent to each thread will depend, in part, how quickly the messages are processed, and which version of MQ you are connecting to.

However, you mention subscribers in the question (and the code you quote declares a topic as well as the queue). Are you creating a subscription to the topic elsewhere in the app and then using this code to receive messages sent to that subscription? If so, then it's possible that your "queue receiving" threads are simply opening up a different queue to the one that is holding the subscription messages. How is the initial subscription being created?

Comment: I am subscribing to the topic. I am subscribing to the queue directly and I am using MQ Version 8.0. I am creating three individual tasks (`Task.Factory.StartNew`) which will have their own instances for my class containing the quoted Subscribe() method.

Comment: A normal, managed subscription in MQ will use a system queue to hold published messages before they are dispatched to the active subscriber. This queue will have a different name to the topic on which the subscription was created.

Comment: Assuming you've created an unmanaged subscription, with an MQQueue named "devQueue" as the MQDestination when you subscribe, then you should be able to use that MQQueue to receive messages. Do you use the option MQC.MQSO_MANAGED when you subscribe? If so, try removing the option. By default,  MQ will use a LIFO ordering when sending messages to waiting consumers. This is for performance reasons, and does mean that you will favour one consumer until it cannot handle all incoming messages and will then "spill over" to the next consumer. This could be why only one thread is getting messages.